# Do conversation choices in heart events have an effect on friendship?

Tags: stardew-valley

During heart events, residents of Pelican Town give us response options that often vary widely in tone. I know these choices can change dialogue at later heart events, but beyond that I’m curious of their results. Do these choices affect friendship, or have any other in-game effects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, some of the dialog choices affect friendship. The random questions are usually less important, but most can give at least a small boost. Some also lose relationship points if you are a jerk.

Comment: You can even check out the specific values of the different events on the villagers specfic wiki page (ie. [Abigail](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Abigail))